# regex match cond1 OR match cond2 in single command

Tags: php, regex

I need to check if entered date is between 2019-09-01 - 2019-12-31
I can do this as follows: $koodi is user input

```
$pattern1 = "/^2019-(09|11)-([0-2][0-9]|30)$/";
$pattern2 = "/^2019-(10|12)-([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/";

if(preg_match($pattern1, $koodi) || preg_match($pattern2, $koodi)) {
   echo "<code>$koodi</code> ok!<br>\n";
}
else {
  echo ("<code>$koodi</code> NOT ok!<br>\n");
}
```

I was trying to make those two conditions into single regex statement, is that possible and if so how?
I tried:

```
$pattern = "/^2019-(09|11)-([0-2][0-9]|30)$ | ^2019-(10|12)-([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/";
```

Did not work, neither the following where i tried to put parentheses around conditions:

```
$pattern = "/(^2019-(09|11)-([0-2][0-9]|30)$) | (^2019-(10|12)-([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$)/";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't use a regex to do that, what if the dates change or what if the next developer has to come and work on this and figure out what your doing?

According to [this article](https://www.freeitsolution.com/php-check-if-current-date-is-between-two-dates-example/) you can check if a date is between 2 dates by doing something like this.

```php
<?php

$currentDate = date('Y-m-d');
$currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate));

$startDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("01/09/2019"));
$endDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("01/10/2019"));

if (($currentDate >= $startDate) && ($currentDate <= $endDate)){
    echo "Current date is between two dates";
}else{
    echo "Current date is not between two dates";  
}
```

as for why your patterns didn't work its because you have a space around the pipe in the middle and you may possibly need to wrap the whole thing in brackets. You also have the $ half way through the regex which is matching the whole string, I would usually only have it at the end, like this: -

`^(regex1|regex2)$`

I haven't written the correct version in case your tempted to use it, (please use the date objects method)